# Can't receive data from $_GET

Tags: php

I just moved my site to a different server. And i'm amazed why my scripts can't receive data from $_GET array. I wrote my scripts considering `register_globals = Off ($id = $_GET['id'])`. On the previous server, everything works fine, but not on this one.

I use a simple test file (test.php), acces it like : `test.php?do=123`
And in this files i wrote this simple condition:

```
if(isset($_GET['do'])) {echo "yes";}
```

**UPDATE:** When i check `if(isset($_GET)) {echo "yes";}` I can see the "yes" string,
`print_r($_GET);` displays me this :

```
Array ( [/text_php] => )
```

The script doesn't display me something. 
What can be the reason? Thank you.

Comment: Is that everything you have in your script? What result do you get?

Comment: Try `print_r($_GET);` (without any conditions)/.

Comment: Are you using normal PHP opening tag (<?php ?>) or short open tag (<? ?>)?

Comment: @Daan it's just a test file. My another files are included in index.php corresponding to `$_GET['do']`, for example `if(isset($_GET[do])) {$do = $_GET['do']; include("{$do}.php");}`, and when i acces index.php?do=aboutus , aboutus.php is not loaded.

Comment: try `if(isset($_GET)) {echo "yes";}` . did shown 'yes'?

Comment: @MehmanBashirov, yes it is.

Comment: then `print_r($_GET);` and write result here please

Comment: Array ( [/text_php] => ) - That's what i receive.

Comment: @MehmanBashirov , just updated my question

Comment: did you put the head `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>`. try

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't working.

Answer (score 0):

maybe php is not the default language for web server. Use `<?php ... ?>` for your php files.

for example:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['do'])) {echo "yes";}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you. But this is not the problem. All my code is contained nside of `<?php ... ?>`